# What is meant by deleting the last thing you wrote?

Tags: technique, editing

One writing tip I saw was, cutting the last thing you wrote because often it is unimportant, but I think I need a little more direction in what way I should do it.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Where exactly did you see this writing tip, and what exactly is your dilemma when trying to follow it? I'm guessing you're struggling with how to define "the last *thing* you wrote" - is it the last sentence? The last paragraph? The last page? - but I don't want to write an answer based on that assumption only to find out that your *actual* dilemma is something entirely different.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I don't know when to use it. Everything seems important to me, but might not be if someone else looked over it, but if I would just cut it everytime...that also wouldn't be the right thing to do.

Comment: Can you give a link to the source that suggested this?

Comment: It feels like the context of the advice is missing. Please provide more details to get better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That advice is sometimes given as a strategy to overcome writer's block, especially when you are discovery writing.

The idea is that if you have written yourself into a corner and don't know how to go on from there, deleting the last (several) part(s) that you have written and starting fresh from somewhere earlier in the story might help to get you out of that dead end.

This technique was shared by Australian writer Max Barry on his website in a post titled "[The Block](https://maxbarry.com/2005/10/29/news.html)" on October 29, 2005. Barry explains that when you encounter writer's block the

> possibility is that your story has good fundamentals but you took a wrong turn. ... A trick I use when suddenly I go from powering along to a dead halt is to delete the last sentence. Even if I think there’s nothing wrong with it: backspace backspace backspace. For some reason, this almost always immediately presents me with an idea for a new way forward. Sometimes I have to delete a paragraph or two, or (very rarely) even a whole chapter. I don’t know why the physical act of cutting part of the story away helps ... [b]ut ... it does.

I think it's a good strategy, if being stuck in a dead end is the cause for your writer's block. There are many other causes that cannot be resolved in this way. Cutting what you have written might be emotionally difficult, though, especially for those writers who write to express themselves, because it requires that you are able to let go (part of) what you have created. But you should learn that anyway, if you want to become more professional.

I would only add that I wouldn't actually *delete* what I had written, especially if it was several paragraphs of even a whole chapter, but rather cut and paste it to some other document or save a version of my text. Taking it out of the story is easier that way, because my effort isn't lost, and I will be able to use it elsewhere, if I want.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, the person didn't give much context, but in that way I see how that helps.